# page reopens on Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a child page (page opned via window.showModalDialog )

I have some code on `.cs` page which calls `javascript` method as :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "SomeMethod();", true);
```

`SomeMethod` is `javascript` function located on same child page opened via `window.showModalDialog`.

This function contains nothing but one alert.

When I call this function , separated window is getting reopened and alert is coming.

Why is it so? Why its not giving alert on same child window?

Comment: Can you share more of your code to give this some context?

Comment: @DSLR Could you provide the javascript code that gets executed?